# Callback concept and normal calling

Tags: c++, c

I'm so confused

we know that all functions defined as global so we can call and use any function inside any block without passing it as argument

why we use Function callback concept while we can use a function inside any function without passing it

so why we use callback concept ?

Comment: A different callback might be needed in various circumstances at run-time. An example is `qsort` library function. In any case the library function was already compiled before it knew anything about your use for it.

Comment: "we know that all functions defined as global so we can call and use any function inside any block without passing it as argument", wut? Generally callbacks are used when a function isn't in the scope of the other, you can pass a function pointer in order to use a function out of the scope where it could be called. The classic example is a sort function, it's explained rather well here [Function pointers](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/)

Comment: Because sometimes you just don't know what function should be called in compile time, see `qsort`. Also, using global scoped functions for classes in C++ is generally frowned upon, especially when it may break incapsulation.

Comment: I view callback functions differently.  We use the callback mechanism when we want another program (say the OS) to do something for our program (or notify us).  For callback, I'd say that the canonical example would be thread creation, where we define and implement a function that get passed by a pointer to the thread create function.  At some point the OS then calls back into our process space and creates a thread running the program we specified.

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason you use variables instead of constants.

Passing a callback to a function allow that function to call a different callback depending on how it was called.

Calling a function by name inside a function will always call that one function.

Answer (score 0):

The call back concept means to provide some other function with a function to call when it needs something to be done, e.g. when an event happens. It also often means we can change the function to be called in run-time.

In this way, the knowledge of when to call what is not needed by the calling function. For example, a 3rd party library defines callbacks for the user's program to "plug-in" functionality into the library, or to be called when an event occurrs, a state is reached or an error occurrs and the library needs to know what to do about the error.

This is just a simple answer. Google around to find more information and see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)